# Using 2 Passports

Tags: passports, airports, uk-citizens, dual-nationality

We are dual UK - Australian citizens visiting Manchester for five weeks. We will leave Australia on our Australian passports.

Is it OK for my wife and I to enter on my UK passport to perhaps save time at Manchester airport?

Are there any other advantages to having a UK passport in the UK?

Comment: I suspect that it is not okay for your wife to enter on your UK passport, since she is probably not listed in it.  If she is a UK citizen, she should probably have her own UK passport.

Answer (score 5):

It is fine to leave Australia on your Aussie passport and present your UK passport when you arrive.  It's common practice for [dual nationals](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/118578/dual-citizens.pdf).

Upon arrival, join the EU queue. And yes, it will be faster *most of the time*.  They are entitled to ask how long you have been out of the UK and where you have been since you last left.

For your other question: *are there any other advantages to having a UK passport once you are landside*, the answer is yes.  You have 1/2 of the documentation needed to open a bank account for example.  You can [instruct a solicitor](http://www.parliament.uk/briefing-papers/SN03086.pdf), do [business with an auction house](http://www.barnardmarcusauctions.co.uk/Auction_Procedure.html), or do any other similar activity where you have to clear money laundering hurdles.  You can take out a long-term lease in and around Brum without having to clear [immigration hurdles](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/landlords-immigration-right-to-rent-checks) if that's of any use.

Plus if you get stopped by the police and show your UK passports you will not be given 3 days to report to a police station to prove your immigration status.